# What is the purpose of Popup in XAML Metro apps?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

I needed a modal dialog for my app but it appeared there is nothing like that in XAML Metro app. Someone suggested a popup.

I tried and it appeared that underlying UI still responsive.. so a Popup is not modal.

I thought OK may be its purpose is to be a popup in the center of the screen regardless the other layout and it appeared - not. Popup is bound to a layout as everything else. if it is in a grid it will be placed in row 0 and column 0 not in the center..

So may be I missing something. please help to understand. I cant find any use for it different from what can be achieved by using Grid.

**what is the purpose of Popup?** how it different from any other content controls?

Comment: when you use popup , have the popup width and height to screen size, and inside the main popup create a div for your content. when you invoke the popup change opacity for the main popup and override opacity for your content div. This will make underlying disabled. I assume you dont have masterpage.

Comment: its xaml project. there is no divs.. but i do something similar yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Differences:

1. You don't have to put it as a child of another control. Though in such scenarios you might get problems traversing the visual tree and focusing on a TextBox won't shift its contents so the virtual keyboard might cover its contents or its adorner contents might lose alignment to adorned controls not on the Popup.
2. Its content tree is rendered on top of any other content and (I believe) doesn't get clipped by parent control's Clip regions.
3. You usually need to set its Width and Height manually when first showing or when parent layout (or size) changes, especially in one of the most common scenarios when you set its Width and Height to the Width and Height of the parent (or the window).

That said - modal dialogs are bad UI and should be avoided. You can simply navigate to another page if you would otherwise want to display a dialog or use other approaches. There's (almost) nothing more annoying than displaying a modal dialog over UI that looks otherwise enabled but doesn't respond to input.

Comment: are you saying that a Popup does not need to have been placed in a visual tree in order to show it? really?

Comment: Yes. You can just do `new Popup {Child = new TextBlock {Text = "Hello"}, IsOpen=true};`, but I would discourage that other than in simple test code.

Answer (score 1):

> I needed a modal dialog for my app but it appeared there is nothing like that in XAML Metro app. Someone suggested a popup.

Since Windows 8.1, there is actually something similar to a modal dialog that you may want to look into:
It's called [Flyouts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465341.aspx).

Comment: The modal dialog is not in XAML, it's Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.popups.messagedialog.aspx

Comment: Yes, but the Flyout is in XAML, correct ?
@BoppityBop said he needed a modal dialog in XAML, I thought Flyout would be a good choice to go with.

Comment: My understanding of the question is that he's looking for a modal dialog behavior, which is MessageDialog. I was pointing out that that UI is not in XAML directly, but in Windows.UI.Popups. But of course you can use a XAML flyout if you manually enforce modal behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently a modal popup with custom content is missing in Windows 8.1. One possible workaround:

1. use a `Popup` control (per se not modal)
2. make the background semi-transparent
3. stretch it across the entire screen
4. place the actual popup content inside that container and leave some space around it

Now, the parent page is visible but dimmed, and it cannot be accessed as the `Popup` is covering it.